# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\E-Commerce\resources\views\orders\order.blade.php)

Tags: laravel-7

commerce application, I have Order table and OrderProduct table, whenever I save order the order and the order_products tables are working fine, but when I want to retrieve all the order_products I got that error. I don't what am missing. Thanks for your help, Here is my code.

This is my Order table

```
class Order extends Model
{

    use AsSource;

    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'billing_email', 'billing_first_name', 'billing_last_name', 'billing_address',
        'billing_city', 'billing_town', 'billing_postalcode', 'billing_phone', 'billing_total', 'error'
    ];

    public function user() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function product() 
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->withPivot('quantity');
    }
}
```

This is my OrderProduct table

```
class OrderProduct extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'order_product';

    protected $fillable = ['order_id', 'product_id', 'quantity'];
}
```

This is my method

```
public function show(Order $order, Request $request)
{
    $order = Order::where('id', $request->order->id)->first();
    $products = $order->product();

    // dd($products);
    return view('orders.order')->with([
        'products' => $products,
        'order' => $order
    ]);
}
```

and if I dd($products) I got Null

And here is my route

```
Route::get('order/{order?}', [\App\Http\Controllers\OrderProductController::class, 'show'])->name('platform.order.edit');
```

Thanks for your concern!.

Comment: What do you get if you ```dd($request->order->id)```

Comment: I got the the id of the order

Answer (score 0):

Try like this and what do you get ?

```
$order = Order::with('product')
    ->where('id', $request->order->id)
    ->first(); 
return $order;
```

Let we know if get an error

Comment: this is what I get  "Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null"